# simulate sarima time series from a fitted models

Tags: r, forecasting

I want to simulate time series based on a fitted SARIMA model. I tried following using the smooth library in R. Is there another way to do this using forecast package

```
x <- ts(100 + c(1:100) + rnorm(100,0,15),frequency=12)
ourModel <- auto.ssarima(x, h=18, silent=TRUE)
ourData <- simulate(ourModel, nsim=50, obs=100)
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the help file for simulate.Arima from the forecast package?